# RAID 5 with parity rebuild after failure

Tags: external-hard-drive, raid

Does anyone have experience rebuilding their RAID 5 drive after failure?

This [OWC enclosure](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/M3QX2KIT0GB/) is the particular model I had in mind.

I was looking into a OWC drive RAID 5 enclosure but could not find much information on what the actual process would be like if a drive failed and I had to recover data from parity.

Would I have to work from proprietor software interface that is very technical or would I be able to manage this from macOS?

Would I be able to run a test of rebuilding the drive set, sort of like a dry run before I load all my data so that I am prepared once there is a system error?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Usually, when a drive fails in a RAID 5 array, you're able to just take the bad disk out and put a replacement in. The controller should recognize the new drive and begin rebuilding by itself.

Comment: @ChrisPowell the controller meaning software inside OWC?

Comment: I'm not sure about that particular model. But, it appears to be hardware RAID.  When you're dealing with RAID, you either have software RAID, or Hardware RAID. Hardware RAID has a controller card in it that controls all RAID functionality. Software RAID is controlled by the OS on a host computer.

Comment: So, the controller card in the enclosure would be in charge of rebuilding the array when you put in a new drive.   
  
But, be careful, RAID 5 only allows you to lose one drive at a time. If you lose another drive while the array is rebuilding then you will lose all data on the array. You should consider getting a model that supports RAID 6, where you can lose any two drives and still be fine.